# Multi master with some slaves vs single master with some slaves

Tags: postgresql, replication, high-availability, failover, postgresql-12

I need some advice on architecture.

I have a national database that relies on postgres and some architectural design that involves orchestrating several components, very much similar to the picture found [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/09/28/high-availability-for-enterprise-grade-postgresql-environments/). We want to achieve HA and scaleability.

Now, before I move further with the proposal, I have a couple of questions :

1. What considerations need to be taken before choosing `multi-master` replication vs `master-slave` replication?
2. which one is easier to maintain: multi masters or master - slave ?

   2.a. If `master - slave` configuration is setup in such a way so that the slave can act as master in case the primary master goes down, isn't it the same as `multi masters` configuration?
3. How do we know which one suits well to answer the problem?

thank you for any advice or perhaps there are some readings that I can read?

Comment: That's easy: as there is no multi-master replication for Postgres, you can only use a classical master-slave replication.

Comment: But I read here https://hevodata.com/learn/postgresql-multi-master-replication/, it says multimasters is configuration that allows multiple nodes to have write access @a_horse_with_no_name